# Подгрузка одного js-файла в другом js-файле

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Как известно, тег `<script>` в javascript файлах не работает. В PHP, HTML файлах подключение javascript кода происходит именно в теге `<script src="~">`. А как же подключить к js-файлу другой  js-файл? Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Подключить в js-файл другой js-файл не получится, поэтому придется пользоваться src и вешать исполнение нужных функций на загрузку страницы.
Хотя, есть возможность динамически создать тег script, задать ему src и подключить в, допустим, head. Но, скорее всего, его содержимое выполнится после того, как отработает функция.

Comment: Натолкнулся на requirejs. Погуглите быть может это то, что нужно

Comment: @culebre, вы мне или Asen'у? =)